# JavaScript show/hide div using asp RadioButtonList

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css

I am working on a ASPX project with .VB in the code behind. The goal is to have two divs hidden when the page loads. Then when the user clicks the "No" radio button it will display the hidden div under it. The Radio buttons are asp List Items.

The code below works but on page load the divs are visible. I'm assuming it is either my VB code or the JS code not hiding on page load.

Here's the VB code behind.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
For Each li As ListItem In rbPickUpOnTime.Items
    If li.Value = "Y" Then
        li.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:hidePickup();")
    End If
    If li.Value = "N" Then
        li.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:showPickup();")
    End If
Next

For Each li As ListItem In rbDeliveryOnTime.Items
    If li.Value = "Y" Then
        li.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:hideDelivery();")
    End If
    If li.Value = "N" Then
        li.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:showDelivery();")
    End If
Next
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
function hidePickup() {
document.getElementById('pnlPickupNo').style.display = 'none';
};

function showPickup() {
document.getElementById('pnlPickupNo').style.display = 'block';
};

function hideDelivery() {
document.getElementById('pnlDeliveryNo').style.display = 'none';
};

function showDelivery() {
document.getElementById('pnlDeliveryNo').style.display = 'block';
};
```

Finally here's one of the ASPX panels it needs to show/hide:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
<div class="centerContainer" style="width: 230px;">
<label class="Emphasis">I can pickup on time </label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbPickUpOnTime" runat="server"
 RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
 Style="margin-left: 60px;" TabIndex="2" AutoPostBack="false">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Y" Selected="True" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="N" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>
  <asp:Panel ID="pnlPickupNo" runat="server" >
 <div class="centerContainer ui-widget-content" style="width: 230px;">
    <label>If No, ETA to pickup </label>
      <table style="margin-left: 15px;">
       .....
     </table>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see how your javascript code works at all.  You can't find an asp.net control using the id like that unless you set `ClientIDMode = Static`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use JavaScript, you could make an OnClick event in your RadioButtonList

```
OnSelectedIndexChanged="yourBehindCodeFunction"
```

and make add runat="server" and an ID to all of your div's, then grab the id in the behind code and set visible to false

```
HTML
div class="centerContainer ui-widget-content" style="width: 230px;" runat="server" ID="test">

Behind-Code
var list = sender as RadioButtonList;
if(list.SelectedValue.Equals("No"))
    test.Visible = false;
```

If you are using JavaScript, you either need to make all of your controls static to use document.getElementById or you could use JQuery and call each by

```
$('#<%= yourControlId.ClientID %>').hide()
```

Comment: I was directed to use JavaScript to avoid a callback. I would prefer to use jQuery if possible.

Comment: With JQuery you can use that final line to hide the div by replacing the "yourControlId" with the html id of the div

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  .Net 4.0 or higher , you can use the Client ID Mode **Static** to generate the **same ID's** in the server side.

If you are not mentioning any thing, then you have use **ClientID's** instead of directly using ID

For example, if your id is   `'pnlPickupNo'`   , then you can client ID's by using below syntax:

```
<%# 'pnlPickupNo'.ClientID %>
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

The question was: How do I make the divs hide onload? 
This is a work project. I was told to use JavaScript to remove the need for a callback in the code behind.

Here's the simple answer I came up with:
JavaScript:

```
function hideDiv() {
    document.getElementById("pnlPickupNo").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("pnlDeliveryNo").style.display = 'none';
};
```

Markup:

```
body tag  onload="hideDiv()"
```

As you can see it is a simple pure JavaScript solution. It works and saves me time.
Thanks everyone for your suggestions.